# How to safely uninstall Docker on Windows Server 2019 VPS

Tags: docker, hyper-v, uninstall, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows Server 2019 VPS(!) machine.
Windows Server 2019 keeps recreating folder "C:\ProgramData\docker", even after I manually removed it.

**Attempt 1:** There's no mention of Docker in my installed programs, so I can't easily uninstall it.

I then tried what's listed here: https://github.com/docker/docs/issues/5905

> PS C:\Users\Administrator> UnInstall-Package Docker -ProviderName
> DockerProvider -Force UnInstall-Package : Unable to find package
> providers (DockerProvider). At line:1 char:1
>
> - UnInstall-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerProvider -Force
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...ninstallPackage:UninstallPackage)
>   ```
>
> [Uninstall-Package    ], Exception
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnknownProviders,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.UninstallPackage
>
> PS C:\Users\Administrator> UnInstall-Module DockerProvider -Force
> PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package : No match was found for the
> specified search criteria and module names 'DockerProvider'. At
> C:\Program
> Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:2194
> char:21
>
> - ...        $null = PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package @PSBoundParameters
> - ```
>                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...ninstallPackage:UninstallPackage)
>     [Uninstall-Package]    , Exception
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.UninstallPackage

**Attempt 2:** I then ran `.\docker-ci-zap.exe -folder "C:\ProgramData\docker` (see https://github.com/jhowardmsft/docker-ci-zap/blob/master/docker-ci-zap.exe) which removed all containers and the folder, but after a VPS restart it's simply back again.

**Attempt 3:** I opened Server Manager and saw that server role "Hyper-V" is enabled.

I now suspect that this is creating the docker folder, but I'm not sure. Is it safe to remove this role and won't it break my VPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the PowerShell script
[CleanupAfterDocker.ps1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/nav-arm-templates/master/CleanupAfterDocker.ps1),
as described in the article
[Clean up after yourself Docker](https://freddysblog.com/2018/12/11/clean-up-after-yourself-docker-your-mom-isnt-here/).
The script cleans up all traces of Docker from the computer before
running `docker-ci-zap.exe`.

If you can see Docker in *Settings > Apps*,
then you may click it and uninstall from there.

Answer (score 1):

Grain of salt: I have never used Docker, but I do know Windows Server & google. Here is what I found, if its any help feel free to upvote.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon#how-to-uninstall-docker

1. Stop docker

> ```
> docker swarm leave --force
> docker ps --quiet | ForEach-Object {docker stop $_}
> docker system prune --volumes --all
> ```

2. Uninstall

> ```
> Uninstall-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
> Uninstall-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider
> ```

3. More things I won't put here because you should read all the details before you make changes that have adverse effects